# how to auto refresh div value when add/edit value in Sql table?

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 .net with Entity Framework.

I want to design client dashboard with list out latest data from sql database.

so how to call ajax method or refresh particular table/div value whenever any value add/edit from other source in database.

I want to call function/ajax method only when any value add/edit in database from any other source without unnecessary auto refresh using `setInterval` function.

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: what i can use here,? any push service, signalR, any third party library!!.

Comment: you need to use signalR. you can call ajax request from server side Hub method using signalR

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of accomplishing this.

1. Easiest is to simply poll the data at set intervals from the server. And when it changes update. To the user this will look like changes are getting pushed out. This will also not require you to do anything special besides calling what you are already doing except in a `setInteraval`
2. You could implement websockets. This enables you to literally push data from the server to a javascript function. The support for this is pretty widespread, and there are many great tutorials for this.
3. Implement a framework like SignalR. This is your most complete and most bakward compatible solution. If there is support for websockets it will be used otherwise it will fall back to simple ajax calls.

Personally Id opt for option 1. unless you have some major traffic or the queries are super heavy to compute on the server. You could even implement a second API that you can call to check for updates very frequently, the second api might return an integer, if that integer is higher than last time we know there is an update and we should make the big heavy query. If this dosent work go for signalR or something similar. https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/68rgxq/signalr_alternatives/